# Error: Could not find or load main class MainKt in IntelliJ

Tags: intellij-idea, kotlin, build-error, kotlin-js

I'm using IntelliJ.
I can run Java or Kotlin project without any issue but 
I can't build Kotlin-JS project
I have the error Error: Could not find or load main class MainKt

My IntelliJ information
 
 
IntelliJ IDEA 2018.2.6 (Community Edition)
 
Build #IC-182.5107.16, built on November 6, 2018
 
JRE: 1.8.0_152-release-1248-b22 amd64
 
JVM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o
 
Linux 4.19.0-041900-generic

File tree
[File tree](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tmNHE.png)

My main file contain just :

```
    fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    val message = "Hello JavaScript!"
    println(message)
}
```

Run Menu
[Run menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6AR0y.png)

I tried the option $KOTLIN_BUILDED$, $MODULE_WORKIN_DIR$, and to put the path manually but it didn't change anything.

When I'm hovering MainKt with my mouse, a tooltip appear "Class 'MainKt' is in the default package"  so IntelliJ see the class.

My project settings seem to be ok

[Project Structure part 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MoKsd.png)

[Project Structure part 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QcYUn.png)

[Project Structure part 3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N26Pn.png)

I also tried to

Delete the *.iml file
 
Reinstalle IntelliJ
 
Re add the main
 
Invalidate cache and restarted

Thanks you in advance

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The "Kotlin" run configuration runs Kotlin/JVM. To run a Kotlin/JS program as a command-line program, you need to make sure you have node.js installed. Then you can either use IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate with the node.js plugin installed (in which case you will see a "run" icon in the gutter that will produce the correct run configuration automatically), or use Gradle to build and run your program from the command line.

Comment: It was not linked to node.js, kotlin can use node.js but I'm note sure it's mandatory. 

But you were right on the run configuration part, since on the IntelliiJ site they say to get started with Gradle or directly into IntelliJ I though that  Kotlin-Javascript would work with just the run command (In some video/site I saw it seem to work for some people) 
But anyway, it works with Gradle, Thanks you.

Answer (score -3):

Your main file need to be `.kt`

You need to create it like this: `src ->New ->Cotlin File/Class->File`.

NOT like this: `src ->New ->File`.

Comment: You can even create file from windows file explorer with .kt extension. It does not matter. Your answer does not have anything to do with question.